# After dropbox down eclipse going crazy - cannot start code

Tags: java, eclipse, tomcat, dropbox

I used dropbox for my workspace in eclipse. I was working on the code then I lost the connection to the internet for 15 min now Im not able to start the code, I get messages like:

```
HTTP Status 404 - /DB/register.jsp

type Status report

message /DB/register.jsp

description The requested resource (/DB/register.jsp) is not available.

Apache Tomcat/7.0.23
```

The path /DB/register.jsp is there, Im in the path right now. And before I was able to start everything there. Whats is going on with eclipse?

**Edit:** Ok a solution was to create a new workspace, new project, new tomcat server then add code => working. Sad that eclipse is so frail.

Answer (score 1):

Tomcat has become confused.  Just restart it.

Comment: im starting tomcat always with eclipse when the I run the code on server so I think thats not the solution because I restarted eclipse, no the whole system and nothing changed.

Answer (score 1):

I'd suggest you to create a new workspace and copy/paste your code in it. Everything should work just fine then.

Comment: Yeah that was one solution... new workspace, new project, new tomcat server then add code => working.